# Server not receives complete requests in each read

Tags: c++, sockets, asynchronous, boost-asio, race-condition

I'm trying to write an async tcp client(client should be capable of writing to the socket without waiting for previous operations' results to arrive).

```
std::future<void> AsyncClient::SomeMethod(sometype& parameter)
{
    return std::async(
        std::launch::async,
        [&]()
        {
            // Gonna send a json. ';' at the end of a json separates the requests.
            const std::string requestJson = Serializer::ArraySumRequest(numbers) + ';';
            boost::system::error_code err;

            write(requestJson, err);
```

write method:

```
void AsyncClient::write(const std::string& strToWrite, boost::system::error_code& err)
{
    // m_writeMutex is a class member I use to synchronize writing.
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_writeMutex);
    boost::asio::write(m_socket,
        boost::asio::buffer(strToWrite), err);
}
```

But result is not what I expected. mostly what I receive on server side is not a complete request followed by ;.

What happens is like:

> A request: `{"Key":"Value"};{"Key":"Va`
>
> Next request: `lue"};{"Key":"Value"};`

Why it's like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually implement the protocol on the receiving end. If you haven't received an entire request, you need to call your receive function again. The socket doesn't understand your application protocol and has no idea what a "request" is -- that's the job of the code that implements the application protocol.

If you haven't received a complete request, you need to receive more. The socket has on idea what a "complete request" is. If that's a complete JSON object, then you need to implement enough of the JSON protocol to find where the end of a request is.

Comment: Thanks. As each request is separated by a ; I can tell my server to read again until you ended up with a complete request. but as number of requests grows it becomes harder for server to randomly end up with a complete request.

Comment: @H.Ebr Then you need to write a parser to receive a bunch of data from the socket, search for semi-colons, and loop. Make sure to save the leftover from the next pass and keep in mind you might receive two or more complete requests in a single read. It's your job to implement the application protocol. The socket has no idea that a request is delimited be a semicolon.

Comment: You should probably ask a new question.

Comment: Just did https://stackoverflow.com/q/64108775/14186665