# mutex on boost::asio::write not works

Tags: c++, sockets, asynchronous, boost-asio, race-condition

I'm trying to make an async tcp client(it's gonna not waits for result of a request before sending another request).

A request method looks like:

```
std::future<void> AsyncClient::SomeRequestMethod(sometype& parameter)
{
    return std::async(
        std::launch::async,
        [&]()
        {
            // Gonna send a json. ';' at the end of a json separates the requests.
            const std::string requestJson = Serializer::ArraySumRequest(numbers) + ';';
            boost::system::error_code err;

            write(requestJson, err);
            // Other stuff.
```

write method calls boost::asio::write like this:

```
void AsyncClient::write(const std::string& strToWrite, boost::system::error_code& err)
{
    // m_writeMutex is a class member I use to synchronize writing.
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_writeMutex);
    boost::asio::write(m_socket,
        boost::asio::buffer(strToWrite), err);
}
```

But looks like still multiple threads do write concurrently as what I receive in server is like:

> {"Key":"Val{"Key":Value};ue"};

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did put the lock guard around **writing to the asio**. There is, as you can see, no guarantee the other end will have them processed with the same guard.

You should rather put the guard where you need it, on **writing the json**, out of the asio:

```
void AsyncClient::write(const std::string& strToWrite, boost::system::error_code& err)
{
    // m_writeMutex is a class member I use to synchronize writing.
//  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_writeMutex);
    boost::asio::write(m_socket,
    boost::asio::buffer(strToWrite), err);
}

return std::async(
    std::launch::async,
    [&]()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_writeMutex); // <--- here

        // Gonna send a json. ';' at the end of a json separates the requests.
        const std::string requestJson = Serializer::ArraySumRequest(numbers) + ';';
        boost::system::error_code err;

        write(requestJson, err);
        // Other stuff.
```

Comment: Was struggling with this for 2 days. THANKS.